# React UseEffect with empty array dont trigger return function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, use-effect

I'm trying to use a return function inside the body of useEffectF, to implement certain logic.

But if I have an empty array of dependencies, the returned function is not called

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // works good
    console.log('useEffect');
    console.log('useEffect', currentFilter , referenceStore.Filters?.CurrentFilter?.FilterId);
    return () => {
        // does not work
        console.log('return function has been called') 
    }
}, []);
```

Any ideas why this behavior is possible? because in the examples and in the documentation everything works ok

thanks advance!

Comment: The returned function in a `useEffect` with an empty array of dependencies only runs when the component unmounts. Is the component your testing unmounting? In other words, how are you testing this to get the expected results?

Comment: it does not unmounting, it just updates
as I understood componentDidUpdate triggered,  
because , the first useeffet fires has dependency, and the second just waits for unmounting and only then will its return function work.
Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core answer: returning a function from a `useEffect` means that this function will be called when the component unmounts. Not on first render, as your question seems to suggests.

If you want to see it called, you can wrap your root component in the `StrictMode` component (will only work if the React version is >= 18). See: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-worker-duzty0?file=/src/App.js

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

The reason *why* it does not fire without strict mode and/or React version < 18 is because of this

> With Strict Mode starting in React 18, whenever a component mounts in development, React will simulate immediately unmounting and remounting the component:

Mount -> log "useEffect"

Unmount -> cleanup fn is called, log "return function has been called"

Mount -> log "useEffect"

As the comment by Brian Thompson underlined, this is only active in development mode, not in a production build.

Comment: This is true, but `StrictMode` is only in effect during development. It mounts - unmounts - and then re-mounts each component to check for side-effects that may be bugs. It also only does this in React 18.

Comment: Absolutely, I edited my quick answer to be a bit more detailed and helpful.

Comment: Looks good. I would also say that the OP using React <18 could just as easily be the cause as not using `StrictMode`.